# Formula to convert quarter-year to MM/DD/YYYY in Excel

Tags: excel, date

I want to convert a column of dates in QTR/YR format to MM/DD/YYYY format, using the first day of the quarter (the first days of the four quarters are Jan. 1, April 1, July 1 and Oct. 1.) How can I go about doing this?

Example:

4Q14 should become 10/01/2014

3Q14 should become 7/01/2014

2Q14 should become 4/01/2014

and so forth.

Comment: I came here looking for nearly the opposite. For anyone like me wanting to convert `2018-02-21` to `2018 Q1`, use `=TEXT(A2,"yyyy")&" Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(A2)/3,0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=Date(Right(A1,2)+2000,CHOOSE(Left(A1,1),1,4,7,10),1)
```

[image]

Comment: Plus one, `CHOOSE` is arguably clearer than my method.

Answer (score 1):

If cell A1 contains the text, then

`=DATE(2000+RIGHT($A$1,2),-2+3*LEFT($A$1,1),1)`

is one way. That will yield a number that you can *format* as a date, using the format of your choice.

Comment: Though I did like your formula approach